# How to upload videos to Google Drive?

Tags: php, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have created Google Service account and successfully connected my app with google drive.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$credentialsFile = 'PATH TO JSON CREDENTIALS';

if (!file_exists($credentialsFile)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Service account credentials Not Found!');
}

$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFile);
$client->setApplicationName("Reflektions Drive");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

I have facing problem to upload videos to google drive. Since the video size is large i get Maximum execution error.

```
$driveService = drive_get_service();
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName('vid.mp4');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('video/mp4');

    $data = file_get_contents(base_url('vid.mp4'));

    $createdFile = $driveService->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'video/mp4',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    ));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($createdFile);
```

Using the same code i have uploaded the image files successfully. And m not being able to display the image in my browser either.
So my questions here are:

1. How to display the uploaded image in browser?
2. How to upload videos (larger files) in google drive?
3. How to embedd the uploaded video in my app?

Here is the snippet of the resumable upload i tried:

I tried the resumable uploads

```
function upload(){    
DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vid.mp4');
            $driveService = drive_get_service();
            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            $file->name = "Big File";
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            $request = $driveService->files->create($file);
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $driveService->getClient(),
                $request,
                'video/mp4',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = $this->readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }
            $result = false;
            if ($status != false) {
                $result = $status;
            }
            fclose($handle);

            echo $result;
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($file);
}     
    function readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSize)
        {
            $byteCount = 0;
            $giantChunk = "";
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = fread($handle, 8192);
                $byteCount += strlen($chunk);
                $giantChunk .= $chunk;
                if ($byteCount >= $chunkSize) {
                    return $giantChunk;
                }
            }
            return $giantChunk;
        }
```

I get Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded error.

Comment: its in the documentation. look for resumable uploads. show us issues using that method.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload and https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-upload.php should help